# Query two different models at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, associations

In my application a `user` can have multiple `clients` of `NaturalPerson` and `LegalPerson` type.

So far I have two tables `NaturalPeople` and `LegalPeople` along with their models, controllers, and routes.

I would like to create a third route so that the end user can query for all his clients (NaturalPeople and LegalPeople) at once.

So I created a `client` model and tried to associate it with the `NP` and the `LP` ones using a faux Multiple Table Inheritance mechanism, since NP and LP are actually clients and have in common some attributes and methods. This trial has not been very successful so I was wondering what would be the best architecture for this use-case.

Comment: I don't quite understand, if you want to query from different tables, why not use a simple join?

Comment: Could you please point out an example of using a simple join. I guess this will happen on the controller?

Comment: I assume that `NaturalPerson` and `LegalPerson` tables each has a `user_id` column to reference the user. If that's the case then you can use a simple join like `User.joins(:natural_people, :legal_people)`. I don't know the specifics of your code so you need to read more about how to join two tables and select the values that you want. Also this would be done in the user model.

Answer (score 0):

When you say both NaturalPerson and LegalPerson where clients. Better way for this case. Making Single Table Inheritance in Clients table as NaturalPerson and LegalPerson as a subsclass.

Check this link http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/